# How to get a 2D shape ready for a Bi-LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, bidirectional

I've got a 2D numpy matrix (from a DataFrame) of already condensed word vectors (I used a max pooling technique, am trying to compare a logres to a bi-LSTM approach), and I'm not sure how to prepare it to use it in a keras model.

I'm aware of the need of a 3D tensor for the Bi-LSTM model, and have tried googling solutions, but couldn't find a solution that worked.

This is what I have right now:

```py
# Set model parameters
epochs = 4
batch_size = 32
input_shape = (1, 10235, 3072)

# Create the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True, input_shape = input_shape)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))

# Try using different optimizers and different optimizer configs
model.compile('adam', 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Fit the training set over the model and correct on the validation set
model.fit(inputs['X_train'], inputs['y_train'],
            batch_size = batch_size,
            epochs = epochs,
            validation_data = [inputs['X_validation'], inputs['y_validation']])

# Get score over the test set
return model.evaluate(inputs['X_test'], inputs['y_test'])
```

I currently got the following error:

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_23: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

The shape of my training data (`inputs['X_train']`) is `(10235, 3072)`.

Thanks so much!

Comment: use **inputs['X_test'].apply(lambda x: np.reshape(x, (1, 10235, 3072)))**

Comment: @BenjaminBreton Thanks for the quick reply! I've tried that, but now I've ended up with the following error: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_29 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (10235, 1)`

Comment: You shouldn't have **return_sequence=True** unless you want to predict one value per sequence element, and in that case, **Dense** sould be **TimeDistributed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made it work with the suggestion of the reply by doing the following:

1. Remove `return_sequence = True`;
2. Apply the following transformations to the X sets: `np.reshape(inputs[dataset], (inputs[dataset].shape[0], inputs[dataset].shape[1], 1))`
3. Change the input shape of the LSTM layer to `(10235, 3072, 1)` which is the shape of `X_train`.